# Number of paths on xy plane

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

How many paths do we have that they start from $(0,0)$ pass firstly from $(3,2)$ then from $(4,5)$ and end up on $(x,y)$ if we can only go up and right.
Is it right to say that the number of path are  $$\frac {(3+2)!}{3!2!} + \frac {(1+3)!}{1!3!}   + \frac {(x-4+y-5)!}{(x-4)!(y-5)!}$$or am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you have a $(1+4)$ term in the second expression?  $5-2=3$ so shouldn't it be $(1+3)$ (and $1!3!$ in the denominator)?

Comment: Sorry my bad I will edit it.

Comment: And did you mean to change the second resting point to $(5,4)$ ?  Pre-edit it had read $(4,5)$.  Once the details have settled, I'll reformat the question to make it more readable.

Comment: I think it is okay now.

Comment: Check my reformatting to make sure I didn't accidentally change your meaning. I don't see a problem with the formula.

Comment: It is okay now. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @lulu These tasks are not mutually exclusive.  Mitsos should have multiplied rather than added.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Indeed.  I was so focussed on the arithmetic error that I didn't even look at the overall form.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have multiplied rather than added.  You apply the [Addition Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) when two tasks are mutually exclusive, which is not the case here.  When you can perform both tasks independently, you apply the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

You are correct that the number of paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(3, 2)$ that only go up or right is 
$$\binom{3 + 2}{2} = \binom{5}{2} = \frac{5!}{2!3!}$$
since we must choose which two of the five paths will be upwards.

You are also correct that the number of paths from $(3, 2)$ to $(4, 5)$ is 
$$\binom{(4 - 3) + (5 - 2)}{3} = \binom{1 + 3}{3} = \frac{4!}{1!3!}$$
since we must choose which three of the four paths will be vertical and the number of paths from $(4, 5)$ to $(x, y)$ is
$$\binom{(x - 4) + (y - 5)}{y - 5} = \frac{(x + y - 9)!}{(x - 4)!(y - 5)!}$$
since we must choose which $(y - 5)$ of the $(x - 4) + (y - 5)$ paths will be vertical.

However, for each of the $\binom{5}{2}$ ways we can proceed from $(0, 0)$ to $(3, 2)$, we can proceed from $(3, 2)$ to $(4, 5)$ in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways.  By the Multiplication Principle, there are 
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{3}$$
paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(4, 5)$ that pass through the point $(3, 2)$.  By similar reasoning, the number of paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(x, y)$ that pass through both $(3, 2)$ and $(4, 5)$ is 
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{3}\binom{x + y - 9}{y - 5}$$